# Размещение на хостинг Tornado сервера

Tags: python, сервер, hosting, tornado

Как мне разместить свой Tornado сервер на каком либо хостинге? Основная проблема заключается в том что все руководства в интернете (даже английские) используют старые классы WSGIAplication версии Tornado <6.0.
Я же хочу использовать Tornado версии 6.1, однако понятия не имею как это правильно сделать (руководства по размещению серверов сделанных на flask, django не подходят т.к. Tornado использует ассинхронный подход и wsgi для таких целей просто не подходит) Использую хостинг TimeWeb. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: купи машинку виртуальную.

Comment: Можете скинуть какой либо сервис подходящий для этого?

Comment: https://vdsina.ru/?partner=1xv5fk5qgv  - регаешь там убунту, стандартный сервер 1 гиг 1 ядро - 6 рублей в день.